# R: Interpolation of values for NAs by indices/groups when first or last values aren't given

Tags: r, interpolation, missing-data

I have panel data that has county data for 15 years of different economic measures (which I have created an index for). There are missing data in the values that I would like to interpolate. However, because the values are randomly missing by year, linear interpolation doesn't work, it only gives me interpolation values between the first and last data points. This is a problem because I need interpolated values for the entire series.

Since all of the series have more than 5 data points, is there any code out there that would interpolate the series based on data that already exists within the specific series?

I first thought about indexing my data to try and run a loop but then I found code on linear interpolation by groups. While the latter solved some of the NA's it did not interpolate all of them. Here would be an example of my data that interpolates some of the data but not all.

`library(dplyr)`

```
data <- read.csv(text="
index,year,value
1,2001,20864.135
1,2002,20753.867
1,2003,NA
1,2004,17708.224
1,2005,12483.767
1,2006,12896.251
1,2007,NA
1,2008,NA
1,2009,9021.556
1,2010,NA
1,2011,NA
1,2012,13795.752
1,2013,16663.741
1,2014,19349.992
1,2015,NA
2,2001,NA
2,2002,NA
2,2003,NA
2,2004,NA
2,2005,NA
2,2006,NA
2,2007,NA
2,2008,151.108
2,2009,107.205
2,2010,90.869
2,2011,104.142
2,2012,NA
2,2013,128.646
2,2014,NA
2,2015,NA")
```

Using

```
interpolation<-data %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  mutate(valueIpol = approx(year, value, year, 
                            method = "linear", rule = 1, f = 0, ties = mean)$y)
```

I get the following interpolated values.

```
1,2001,20864.135
1,2002,20753.867
1,2003,19231.046
1,2004,17708.224
1,2005,12483.767
1,2006,12896.251
1,2007,11604.686
1,2008,10313.121
1,2009,9021.556
1,2010,10612.955
1,2011,12204.353
1,2012,13795.752
1,2013,16663.741
1,2014,19349.992
1,2015,NA
2,2001,NA
2,2002,NA
2,2003,NA
2,2004,NA
2,2005,NA
2,2006,NA
2,2007,NA
2,2008,151.108
2,2009,107.205
2,2010,90.869
2,2011,104.142
2,2012,116.394
2,2013,128.646
2,2014,NA
2,2015,NA
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm pretty new to R and have never worked with loops but I have looked up other "interpolation by groups" help. Nothing seems to solve the issue of filling in data when the first and last points are NA's as well.

Comment: For those elements that are NA for the first and last, how do you want to fill it?  Try `library(zoo); data %>% group_by(index) %>% mutate(valueIpol = na.approx(value, na.rm = FALSE)) %>% fill(valueIpol, .direction = 'up') %>% fill(valueIpol, .direction = 'down')`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I was hoping that they could be interpolated based on the trend of the values that already exist in the series.

Comment: Just realized, your original code already would work....just replace rule = 1 with rule = 2. The NAs are because trailing / leading NAs are ignored with rule = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
library(imputeTS)
for(i in unique(data$index)) {
  data[data$index == i,] <- na.interpolation(data[data$index == i,])
}
```

Only works when the groups itself are already ordered by year. (which is the case in your example)

Output would look like this:

```
> data
  index year     value
1      1 2001 20864.135
2      1 2002 20753.867
3      1 2003 19231.046
4      1 2004 17708.224
5      1 2005 12483.767
6      1 2006 12896.251
7      1 2007 11604.686
8      1 2008 10313.121
9      1 2009  9021.556
10     1 2010 10612.955
11     1 2011 12204.353
12     1 2012 13795.752
13     1 2013 16663.741
14     1 2014 19349.992
15     1 2015 19349.992
16     2 2001   151.108
17     2 2002   151.108
18     2 2003   151.108
19     2 2004   151.108
20     2 2005   151.108
21     2 2006   151.108
22     2 2007   151.108
23     2 2008   151.108
24     2 2009   107.205
25     2 2010    90.869
26     2 2011   104.142
27     2 2012   116.394
28     2 2013   128.646
29     2 2014   128.646
30     2 2015   128.646
```

Since the na.interpolation function uses approx internally, you can pass parameters of approx trough to adjust the behavior.

The parameters you used in your example: **method = "linear", rule = 1, f = 0, ties = mean**  are the standard parameters. If you want to use these you don't have to add anything.

Otherwise you would change the part in the loop with for example this:

```
  data[data$index == i,] <- na.interpolation(data[data$index == i,], ties ="ordered", f = 1, rule = 2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to interpolate the NA's based on the values that are already in the series? Rather than repeating the last known value (index 2, value 128.646)

Comment: Well...there is no way to interpolate these values. Trailing / Leading NAs require extrapolation / forecasts. This does not work with solutions based on zoo:na.approx, approx, imputeTS::interpolation. Also take a look at my comment under your original post. Your code already worked, only the rule parameter was set wrong.